# Is this a pattern and if yes, what is its name?

Tags: design-patterns

How do I name this "WorkDistribtor"? This looks like a pattern but I cant's say what it is.

```
interface IWorker
{
    void Do();
}

class WorkerOne: IWorker 
{
    public void Do() {...}
}

class WorkerTwo: IWorker 
{
    public void Do() {...}
}

// ...
```

Instead of using one specific worker to Do() the job I am introducing an indirection that decides which actual worker should do the job. This indirection implements the same interface as a Worker but doesn't actually do the work but delegating it.

```
class WorkDistributor: IWorker
{
    private _workerOne = new WorkerOne();
    private _workerTwo = new WorkerTwo();
    //...

    //delegate work to the different workers
    //depending on some conditions
    public void Do()
    {
      if (whateverCondition)
      {
          _workerOne.Do();
      }

      if (anotherCondition)
      {
          _workerTwo.Do();
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks most likely like the `Strategy` pattern (also known as the policy pattern):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

where you actually allow each specific implementation to define different behavior depending on the context, and algorithms can be selected at runtime using your selector class(the one that defines the actual context).

Comment: The WorkDistributor decides on runtime what strategy (worker) to use, but it hides this fact for the outside world (client) by implementing the same interface as the strategy itself (providing the Do() method). So a client may use a concrete strategy (that is, a specific worker) or the WorkDistrubutor. This can be nicely set by dependency injection. Is this still the strategy pattern?

Answer (score 0):

This is universally called **Interface pattern** :P

Answer (score 0):

What about dubbing it the "Indirection" pattern? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I know it as abstract factory pattern

[Abstract Factory on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)